# Swift - UIView frame is not equal to UIView.layer.frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, equals, layer

I want to draw a UIView layer but when I do it the layer frame is not equal(In Preview) to UIView frame.
[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var graphHeight:CGFloat = 100
    var graphSize:CGFloat!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        graphSize = self.view.frame.height/CGFloat(M_PI)
        let graphRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, graphHeight, self.view.frame.width, graphSize)
        let background = blueGardient()
        var theView:UIView = UIView(frame: graphRect)
        background.frame = theView.frame
        theView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        theView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        theView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        theView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        theView.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)
        self.view.addSubview(theView)

    }

    func blueGardient()->CAGradientLayer{
        let topColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 255, alpha: 0.7)
        let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 255, alpha: 0.9)
        let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
        let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]
        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
        gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations
        return gradientLayer
    }
}
```

The frame is equal

```
(0.0,100.0,320.0,180.800015352393)
(0.0,100.0,320.0,180.800015352393)
```

but not shown eauql. I try with theView.layer.frame but unsuccessfully...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is because the context of each frame is different. Your view frame (`theView.frame`) is in the context of its superview, so the (0,100) origin means it is offset by 100 points downward from the top left of the screen. The layer's frame (`background.frame`) is in the context of the *view it belongs to* (`theView`), so the same (0,100) origin means the blue layer is offset by 100 points from the top left of the *view*.

Instead of using the view's `frame`, create a new rect using the size of the view's `bounds` and a (0,0) origin:

```
background.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: theView.bounds.size)
```

Comment: +1. Technically, though, [`bounds.origin` might not always be (0, 0)](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/04/understanding-uiscrollview/), so I think your second solution is better.

Comment: In addition to @AaronBrager, [`frame` might be invalidated by `transform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame), it preferable to use `bounds.size`.